# Why is RollingFileAppender for log4j not logging in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, logging, log4j

I'm trying to set up log4j for use in a Spring MVC webapp. stdout logging is working perfectly, but neither RollingFileAdapter nor FileAdapter have been able to print my log to a file. 
Here's my log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger option  
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout
# Direct log messages to a log file  
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.file.File=~/logger.log 
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100MB  
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1  
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -     %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout  
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender  
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -     %m%n
```

In web.xml I've defined the listener:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and the context parameter:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I'm using Maven and define the dependency using:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>  
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>  
    <version>1.2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

In my controller I instantiate the logger using

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DeviceController.class);
```

and test it in a method using

```
//Implement required logging method
logger.debug("Debug.."); 
logger.info("Info..");
logger.error("Error..");
logger.fatal("Fatal");
logger.trace("trace");
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Spring MVC3. I've tried several directories for the logging file and have pre-created the paths each time.

I should add I'm also getting the following unexplained error:

```
An error occurred while filtering resources PolicyManager line 1 Maven Configuration Problem
```

but it still compiles and stdout logging works.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the log file is not being created and/or appended?

Comment: Have you tried using full path instead of `~/logger.log`? AFAIK tilda expansion is BASH functionality. Not sure if that is some special log4j feature as well.

Comment: It turns out the permission to write to /home is absent. It worked when writing to a different directory.